# Downloading a repository for local use

Tags: linux, repository, thunderbird

I'm trying to get Thunderbird working in such a way that it will properly work with Kolab groupware. For that I need it to be in a fixed setup of Thunderbird and add-ons (Lightning, SyncKolab) without automatic updates and I need to present version of Thunderbird to be available for the users.

What I hope to achieve is that the repository for Thunderbird as it is now on http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/thunderbird-stable/ will be available on my local server so I always use that version even if Thunderbird goes to a new stable version.

What I hope to achieve is this:
- I copy the content of http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/thunderbird-stable/ to my server
- I make it available as a repository on my network

I neither know if this is possible or allowed under the license etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirroring an APT repository is certainly possible and there are many different procedures to do it.  You could do something as simple as a recursive wget to grab the contents, and then server it with a local web server.  But there are also many tools already available to do this as well.  You could use a tool like `apt-mirror` and so on.  Just do a search for 'APT mirror' for lots of guides about the possible procedures.

As for your question about legality, that is off-topic here.  You should read the `copyright` file included within every package and determine if you are complying with the terms yourself.  If you have any legal questions, then consult a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The legal part wasn't actually a question (although I did put it there like that) more of remark on the side (btw it is legal). My bad. It seems the apt-mirror will do it, I just need to make sure there are no automatic updates to the local repository. Shouldn't be complicated.